# How to join each unique record (based on 2 columns) with every record in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is a bit tricky to explain, but I will do my best.

Say I have two tables:

`Dates` (DateColumn datetime)

`SomeData` (ID1 int, ID2 int, SomeDate datetime)

---

`Dates` ALWAYS contains the following dates:

```
1/1/2012
1/2/2012
1/3/2012
```

---

`SomeData` contains data similar to this:

```
ID  ID1 ID2 SomeDate
1   1   4   1/1/2012
2   1   4   1/2/2012
3   2   3   1/1/2012
4   2   3   1/3/2012
6   5   1   1/2/2012
```

---

Now, notice how in `SomeData`, some of the rows have the same ID1 and ID2 combinations.  Also notice how some of them are missing certain dates found in the `Dates` table.  I need to somehow join each of those combinations with EVERY date in the `Dates` table, to find the missing dates.

So on joining, the data would end up looking like this:

```
ID      ID1 ID2 SomeDate
1       1   4   1/1/2012
2       1   4   1/2/2012
NULL    1   4   1/3/2012 <-- missing from SomeData table

3       2   3   1/1/2012
NULL    2   3   1/2/2012 <-- missing from SomeData table
4       2   3   1/3/2012

NULL    5   1   1/1/2012 <-- missing from SomeData table
6       5   1   1/2/2012
NULL    5   1   1/3/2012 <-- missing from SomeData table
```

Notice how each ID1+ID2 combination each returns 3 records, using all the dates in the `Dates` table, and also notice how each "missing" record maintains the ID1+ID2 combination.  Any idea how I can pull this off?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is your friend here. Here's a full worked example

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE (DateColumn DATETIME)
INSERT @Dates VALUES ('20120101'), ('20120102'), ('20120103')

DECLARE @SomeData TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1), ID1 INTEGER, ID2 INTEGER, 
    SomeDate DATETIME)
INSERT @SomeData VALUES (1,4,'20120101'),(1,4,'20120102'),(2,3,'20120101'),
    (2,3,'20120103'), (5,1,'20120102')


SELECT sd2.ID, sd1.ID1, sd1.ID2, d.DateColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT ID1, ID2
    FROM @SomeData
    GROUP BY ID1, ID2
) sd1
    CROSS JOIN @Dates d
    LEFT JOIN @SomeData sd2 ON sd1.ID1 = sd2.ID1 
            AND sd1.ID2 = sd2.ID2 
            AND sd2.SomeDate = d.DateColumn
```

So to break it down:

1. "sd1" subquery is getting a distinct set of all ID1 and ID2 combinations
2. This is then CROSS APPLY'd to the Dates table. The result of this, is for each ID1+ID2 combination, it will result in a row being returned for each date in the Dates table
3. the final LEFT JOIN then tries to match on the combination of ID1+ID2+Date to return the ID value. This returns NULL as the ID if no match is found, or the ID if it is found.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Wasn't aware of cross join.  Breakdown is also very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    sd.ID,
    ids.ID1,
    ids.ID2,
    d.DateColumn AS SomeDate
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID1, ID2
    FROM SomeData
) ids CROSS JOIN
Dates d LEFT JOIN
SomeData sd 
    ON sd.ID1 = ids.ID1 
    AND sd.ID2 = ids.ID2 
    AND sd.SomeDate = d.DateColumn
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I did not know about cross join.